# React Native App crash after updating targetSdkVersion to 31

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

After Updating targetSdkVersion to 31 that required when upload to store, my application crash directly, but it work well when i return it to 30. What can i do to fix it?


compileSdkVersion = 31

targetSdkVersion = 31

buildToolVersion = 30.0.3

gradle = 4.10.1

gradle plugin = 3.3.1

jvm = 1.8

react native version = 0.62.2

Comment: --> Maybe you can try to change the JVM version to 11.

Comment: You need to upgrade your jdk to version 11

Comment: I tried to change jdk version to 11, but it got some errors: package android does not exist in build tab @Adnansayed

Comment: first of all you can change tagetSdkVersion it is note higher then compile SDK version so you can change your target SDK version 31 to 21 i hope this will help you

Comment: I did not change the configuration. I solved this issue by adding androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0 in app/build.gradle and adding constraints in some modules because they depend on the lower version of work-runtime. 
Ex:  
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
    constraints {
        implementation('androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0') {
            because 'play-services-ads depends on work-runtime:2.1.0 which is not compatible with targetSdk 31, but work-runtime:2.7.0 is'
        }
    }